# Set of reachable nodes in graph using JUNG

Tags: java, reachability, jung

I am looking for an efficient way of finding the set of all nodes that are reachable from specific collection of nodes in JUNG. I am not sure how to do that. One solution would be to get the neighbors of each node of specific collection and do that until no new node added regarding to this process. But I think probably a more efficient way would be available. Could you please tell me what would it be? (below is the code of my implementation)

```
private HashSet<Customer> getReachableNodes(Collection<Customer> churners, DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> net) {

        HashSet<Customer> reachableNode = new HashSet<Customer>();
        for (Customer churner : churners) {
            for(Customer neighbor:net.getVertices()){
                 if(isNeighbor(neighbor,churners,net))   reachableNode.add(neighbor)
            }
        }
        return reachableNode ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward approach could be to do a simple Breadth-first traversal ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search ), but with a collection of "start nodes" instead of a single one:

```
private static <V> Set<V> findReachable(
    Collection<? extends V> startNodes, Graph<V, ?> graph)
{
    Queue<V> queue = new LinkedList<V>();
    Set<V> visited = new LinkedHashSet<V>();
    queue.addAll(startNodes);
    visited.addAll(startNodes);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) 
    {
        V v = queue.poll();
        Collection<V> neighbors = graph.getNeighbors(v);
        for (V n : neighbors)
        {
            if (!visited.contains(n))
            {
                queue.offer(n);
                visited.add(n);
            }
        }
    }
    return visited;
}
```

Comment: From the performance point of view, which one is better? using LinkedHashSet or the normal hashSet?

Comment: Asymptotically, they are equal. E.g. insertion takes O(1) in both cases. Maintaning the linkage in LinkedHashMap will *theoretically* involve some overhead, but it should be negligible (and, for example, iterating over a LinkedHashMap should be faster than iterating over a HashMap)